# Ajax posts filter by date, comments, top views, top likes

Tags: posts, functions, filters, ajax, forms

I'm trying to create a simple Ajax posts filter, It's working with date and comment but not working with the top views or top likes.

So, how can i make the `isset( $_POST['top-views']` and `isset( $_POST['top-likes']` work when I select it.

I'm highly appreciated your help.

form

```
<select name="misha_order_by" id="misha_order_by">
    <option name="top-views" value="top-views">Top Views</option>
    <option name="top-likes" value="top-likes">Top Likes</option>
    <option value="comment_count-DESC">Comments ↓</option>
    <option value="comment_count-ASC">Comments ↑</option>
    <option value="date-DESC">Date ↓</option>
    <option value="date-ASC">Date ↑</option>
</select>
```

Ajax function.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mishainsightsfilter', 'misha_insights_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mishainsightsfilter', 'misha_insights_filter_function');

function misha_insights_filter_function(){

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

    // example: date-ASC 
    $order = explode( '-', $_POST['misha_order_by'] );

    $params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $_POST['misha_number_of_results'], // when set to -1, it shows all posts
        'author' => $current_user->ID,
        'orderby' => $order[0], // example: date
        'order' => $order[1] // example: ASC
    );

      if( isset( $_POST['top-views'] ) )
            $params = array(
                    'author' => $current_user->ID,
                    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'DESC'
       );

      if( isset( $_POST['top-likes'] ) )
            $params = array(
                    'author' => $current_user->ID,
                    'meta_key' => '_post_like_count', 
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'DESC'
       );


    query_posts( $params );

    global $wp_query;

    if( have_posts() ) :

        ob_start(); // start buffering because we do not need to print the posts now

        while( have_posts() ): the_post();

            the_title();

        endwhile;

        $posts_html = ob_get_contents(); // we pass the posts to variable
        ob_end_clean(); // clear the buffer
    else:
        $posts_html = '<p>Nothing found for your criteria.</p>';
    endif;

    // no wp_reset_query() required

    echo json_encode( array(
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ),
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'found_posts' => $wp_query->found_posts,
        'content' => $posts_html
    ) );

    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I haven't tested the code, but this should help.*

`option` elements do not have a `name` attribute:

```
<option name="top-views" value="top-views">Top Views</option>
<option name="top-likes" value="top-likes">Top Likes</option>
```

And therefore `$_POST['top-views']` for example, is not going to be set, or that the value is not the `top-views` in the above `option`.

### Use the proper `option` markup

Based on the following markup:

```
<option value="comment_count-DESC">Comments ↓</option>
```

Your custom `option` should be:

```
<option value="{key}-{order}">{label}</option>
```

So (to sort in DESCending order):

```
<option value="top_views-DESC">Top Views</option>
<option value="top_likes-DESC">Top Likes</option>
```

*Note that the `{key}` should not have a dash (`-`).*

### Parsing the sorting `{key}` and `{order}`

In the `misha_insights_filter_function()` function, the sorting `{key}` (i.e. the `orderby` parameter) and `{order}` are parsed like so:

```
$order = explode( '-', $_POST['misha_order_by'] );
```

So for example, if "Top Views" was selected, and that the `option` value was `top_views-DESC`, then `$order[0]` would be `top_views` and `$order[1]` would be `DESC`.

And you can then customize the `$param` like so:

```php
if ( 'top_views' === $order[0] ) {
  $params['meta_key'] = 'post_views_count';
  $params['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
}
```

Similarly, if "Top Likes" was selected, and that the `option` value was `top_likes-DESC`, you can just copy-paste the above `if` block and replace the relevant values:

```php
if ( 'top_likes' === $order[0] ) {
  $params['meta_key'] = '_post_like_count';
  $params['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @SallyCJ, You are awesome! +1